# Changing toolbar color when in searchable mode (react-native-material-ui)

Tags: react-native

would like to know is there a way to change the toolbar color when it is in searchable ? I have set the toolbar color by "style={{ container: {backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary}}}",  but when click on the search icon, the search bar remains as white...

```
<Toolbar
      style={{ container: {backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary}}}
      centerElement={<Text style={customStyles.title}>Select id</Text>}
      searchable={{
            autoFocus: true,
            placeholder: "Keyword",
            onChangeText: text => searchFilterFunction(text),
            onSearchCloseRequested: () => setName(nameList),
      }}
/>
```

Noticed that the background color of the search bar (when active) is taken from theme as the source state below:

```
  renderAnimatedBackgrounds = styles => {
    const { theme } = this.props;
    const {
      diameter,
      bgPosition,
      radius,
      defaultScaleValue,
      searchScaleValue,
      order,
    } = this.state;

    const bgStyle = {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: -radius,
      width: diameter,
      height: diameter,
      borderRadius: radius,
    };

    const { toolbarSearchActive } = theme;
    const container = StyleSheet.flatten(styles.container);
    const searchActive = StyleSheet.flatten(toolbarSearchActive.container);

    const bgSearch = (
      <Animated.View
        key="searchBackground"
        style={[
          bgStyle,
          {
            left: bgPosition,
            backgroundColor: searchActive.backgroundColor,
            transform: [{ scale: searchScaleValue }],
          },
        ]}
      />
    );
```

However, I have tried to add props "theme= {{ toolbarSearchActive: {container: {backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary }}}}" to toolbar but not taking effect.

Comment: It has `isSearchActive` prop which indicates if the search is active or not, try using it to change background-color.

Comment: Did you get any solution on this, I need to do the same for my app.